# Does "$(\exists f:A\twoheadrightarrow B)\implies(\exists f:B\hookrightarrow A)$" implies the axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, axioms

Let $P$ denotes the property that if there exists a surjection from set $A$ to set $B$, then there exists an injection from $B$ to $A$. It's apparent that $P$ can be proved in ZFC. My question is that if $P$ and AC are equivalent in the ZF theory?

Comment: Short answer, we don't know. See also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905652/millers-construction-partition-principle-and-failure-of-axiom-of-choice) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176972/is-there-a-cantor-schroder-bernstein-statement-about-surjective-maps). Probably a few other related links that I've missed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It surprises me that this question is still open. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: I have a plan to try and solve it, but it might take another 10-20 years or so. But as for the surprise, if there's one thing that I've learned in the past five years of being a grad student and trying to figure out mathematical research, is that it can be very easy to ask questions that can be very hard to answer; it can even be easy to ask *natural* question that arise organically from research (as opposed to just shifting variables of a statement randomly). The tricky part is to find a question that is both natural, non-trivial and that you can still answer it. There lies great mathematics.